# Error with opening an Excel file from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm getting the following error when attempting to open a connection to an excel file:

```
The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already             opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.

at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr,            
OleDbConnection connection) at     
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options,   
Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) at 
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection 
owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at 
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection 
owningConnection) at 
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection 
outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

This problem only occurs when I deploy to a server. I've tried on two different servers: 
32 bit & 64 bit. Both running Windows Server 2008 SP 2. The code works fine on my local machine (Windows 7). I've installed Microsoft office 2007 on both servers as well hoping that a necessary dll would have resolved the issue. The connection string I'm using for the excel file is as follows:

```
string result = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;\"";
```

The _fileName variable is an absolute path to the file's location. I've tried debugging by placing a file directly in the website's directory and set the permissions to full control for all users, but still doesn't work.

I need to query the contents of excel files from my web application and display them to the user. The excel files can have different layouts in the way the data is entered.

Is there anything I'm missing which I need to do in order to get this to work on the server?

Comment: By the way, the file is in fact not open by anyone else. I know because I placed the file on the server myself and set full permissions to it and I didn't open the file. I did double check to make sure the file is not corrupt but it is not open when I run the code.

Comment: The file could be open twice by your own application, in two different requests.

Comment: I agree with John Saunders, I have seen this error when I had the file open previously in the same application, or in another instance of it, and didn't close it and release the reference properly.

Comment: It's not being opened twice, this error happens on the first and only attempt to open the file. I've hardcoded a filename in the code, and placed that file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below link which is very helpful, I solved mine following it.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-7-and-i-have-a-batch-file-to-copy-files/311cdd34-40a2-417c-bb7d-ca96a7ef56ee